# Select ascending and descending on the same field

Tags: sql

```
___________________
| field1 | field1 |
|________|________|
|    A   |   E    |
|    B   |   D    |
|    C   |   C    |
|    D   |   B    |
|    E   |   A    |
|________|________|
```

If possible I do the sql selection like upside table with same field same table?

```
select t1.c, t2.c from
(
    WITH cte AS
    (
        SELECT 
            c,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY c DESC) AS n,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY c ASC) AS m
        FROM @t
    )
    SELECT t1.c, t2.c
    FROM cte t1
    JOIN cte t2 ON t2.n = t1.m
)
```

can i do something like this?

Comment: what database are you using?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
DECLARE @t TABLE ( c CHAR(1) )

INSERT INTO @t
VALUES ('a'),('b'),('c'),('d'),('e')

;WITH cte AS
(
    SELECT 
        c,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY c DESC) AS n,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY c ASC) AS m
    FROM @t
)

SELECT t1.c, t2.c
FROM cte t1
JOIN cte t2 ON t2.n = t1.m
```

*Edit (for comment):*

if you don't want to use a `CTE` then you would write it as

```
SELECT t1.c, t2.c 
FROM ( 
    SELECT c
        , ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY c ASC) AS m 
    FROM @t 
) t1
JOIN ( 
    SELECT c
        , ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY c DESC) AS n
    FROM @t 
) t2 ON t2.n = t1.m
```

#### [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/77832/2)

Comment: ;WITH cte AS
(
    SELECT 
        c,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY c DESC) AS n,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY c ASC) AS m
    FROM @t
)

SELECT t1.c, t2.c
FROM cte t1
JOIN cte t2 ON t2.n = t1.m

this is two sql statement or one sql statement?

Comment: Pretty sure in SQL Server using a CTE will still only result in a single query being executed, but it may be database dependant.

Comment: 'select t1.c, t2.c from(
WITH cte AS
(
    SELECT 
        c,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY c DESC) AS n,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY c ASC) AS m
    FROM @t
)

SELECT t1.c, t2.c
FROM cte t1
JOIN cte t2 ON t2.n = t1.m)'

can i do something like this? @T I

Answer (score 1):

use temptables to add row numbers and you can see in the following fiddle

[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b62be/2)